# How to create a separated column with datatype ObjectId as a foreign key

Tags: mongodb

Goal:
Create a table and a column that has the datatype objectID named phoneId.

This phoneId is a foreign key.

```html
db.createCollection( "Assignment", {
   validator: { $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      required: [ "phoneId" ],
      properties: {
         phoneId: {
            bsonType: "ObjectId",
            description: "must be a object and is required"
         }
      }
   } }
} )
```

The error I get:

```
{
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "errmsg" : "Unknown type name alias: ObjectId",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says the type is wrong. It's `objectId` starting with lowercase "o".